# Landings and stairs

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

Let's have two views of landings and stairs. We obtain the second VIEW B, by rotating the VIEW A 180 degrees clockwise. The distance between two landings is 8 feet, shown by the arrows. The stairs are touching a building. How many doors does each view have? NOTE: I did not draw the total number of steps. Please include your reasoning when you answer.

[image: viewA]

[image: viewB]

Comment: How are we supposed to place the doors? Is it part of the puzzle? Also, can't you please use an image software instead of photographed hand drawings?

Comment: That what the question asks.

Answer (score 5):

> None. There are only stairs and landings in the pictures.

Comment: This is not the correct  answer.